# Text Change color flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to change this screen's below text in black

[image]

and secondly when I type digit the below text shows that `Entered PIN does not match`. instead it shows me after when i complete typed mis-match PIN if i type correct PIN then this Text `Pin must be at least 4 digits. It must not....` should show in black color.

[image]

Here is my full code

```
class _SetPinTestscreenState extends State<SetPinTestscreen> {
  TextEditingController setPinController = TextEditingController();
  

  @override
  void initState() {
    Provider.of<PinValidationProvider>(context, listen: false).isPinSet = false;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MainTemplate(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Consumer<PinValidationProvider>(
                builder: (context, pinProvider, child) {
                  return Text(
                    pinProvider.isPinSet
                        ? 'Re-enter your PIN code to Confirm'
                        : 'Set PIN to Activate your Ending With XXXX',
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 30),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Center(
              child: PinFieldAutoFill(
                decoration: UnderlineDecoration(
                  textStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1.copyWith(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 15,
                      ),
                  gapSpace: 8,
                  lineHeight: 1.2,
                  colorBuilder:
                      PinListenColorBuilder(Colors.black, Colors.grey.shade400),
                ),
                onCodeChanged: (value) {
                  Provider.of<PinValidationProvider>(context, listen: false)
                      .validatePin(value, setPinController);
                },
                codeLength: 4,
                cursor: Cursor(color: Colors.black, enabled: true),
                controller: setPinController,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Consumer<PinValidationProvider>(
              builder: (context, provider, child) {
                final textColor =
                    provider.isInvalidPin || !provider.isPinMatched
                        ? Colors.red
                        : Colors.black;

                if (!provider.isPinMatched &&
                    provider.isPinSet &&
                    setPinController.text.isNotEmpty) {
                  return Text(
                    'Entered PIN does not match.',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  
                  return Text(
                    'Pin must be at least 4 digits. It must not be single digits like'
                    ' 1111 or digits in numerical order such as 1234',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: textColor,
                    ),
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my PinValidationProvider class:

```
class PinValidationProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool _isInvalidPin = false;

  bool get isInvalidPin => _isInvalidPin;
  bool get isPinMatched => confirmedPin == pin;
  bool isPinSet = false;
  String pin = '';
  String confirmedPin = '';

  void validatePin(String pin, TextEditingController controller) {
    if (pin.length != 4) {
      _isInvalidPin = false;
    } else {
      if (_isSimpleSequence(pin) || _isRepeatedDigit(pin)) {
        _isInvalidPin = true;
      } else {
        _isInvalidPin = false;
        if (!isPinSet) {
          isPinSet = true;
          this.pin = pin;
        } else {
          confirmedPin = pin;
        }
      }
      if (confirmedPin != this.pin) {
        controller.clear();
      }
    }
    Future.microtask(() {
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }

  bool _isSimpleSequence(String pin) {
    for (int i = 0; i < pin.length - 1; i++) {
      int digit1 = int.parse(pin[i]);
      int digit2 = int.parse(pin[i + 1]);

      if (digit2 - digit1 == 1) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  bool _isRepeatedDigit(String pin) {
    for (int i = 0; i < pin.length - 1; i++) {
      if (pin[i] == pin[i + 1]) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide PinValidationProvider?

Comment: Added PinValidationProvider class.

Comment: You did take your 4 values in one single controller. I did solve this kind of problem using 4 controllers for 4 values. Can you think about it?

Answer (score 1):

First:

if you want to change the color of "Pin must be at least 4 digits..." text. change to color property Colors.black instead textColor.

```
 return Text(
        'Pin must be at least 4 digits. It must not be single digits like'
        ' 1111 or digits in numerical order such as 1234',
        style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
    ),
);
```

secondly: To achieve

> shows me after when i complete typed mis-match PIN if i type correct
> PIN

You need add and extra validator to if  block, to control user type at least 4 digits.

```
if (!provider.isPinMatched &&
                    provider.isPinSet &&
                    setPinController.text.isNotEmpty && 
        //probably this is your solution
        setPinController.text.length< 4) {
                  return Text(
                    'Entered PIN does not match.',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  );
```

Comment: second approach is working ok but first approach i cant change to color as that condition i am using it previous screen  which is about set PIN screen

Comment: then the only thing that I can suggest you to updating `final textColor =
                    provider.isInvalidPin || !provider.isPinMatched    ? Colors.red : Colors.black;`      In your isInvalidPin validator, if your pin digits are least than 4 you set the textColor to red. You can add extra if block or rearrage it for your expected behaviour

Answer (score -1):

1st

- as i am able to understand that you want to change color of Text("Pin must be at least 4 digits. It must not be single.....") then you have to set it from Text style attribut, ex-

  ```
               Text('Pin must be at least 4 digits. It must not be single digits like'
               ' 1111 or digits in numerical order such as 1234',
               style: TextStyle(
                 color: Colors.black, // i have changed here 
               ),
             );
  ```

2nd-

```
class _SetPinTestScreenState extends State<SetPinTestscreen> {
  TextEditingController setPinController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    Provider.of<PinValidationProvider>(context, listen: false).isPinSet = false;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MainTemplate(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Consumer<PinValidationProvider>(
                builder: (context, pinProvider, child) {
                  return Text(
                    pinProvider.isPinSet
                        ? 'Re-enter your PIN code to Confirm'
                        : 'Set PIN to Activate your Finance House Card Ending With XXXX',
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 30),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Center(
              child: PinFieldAutoFill(
                decoration: UnderlineDecoration(
                  textStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1.copyWith(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 15,
                      ),
                  gapSpace: 8,
                  lineHeight: 1.2,
                  colorBuilder:
                      PinListenColorBuilder(Colors.black, Colors.grey.shade400),
                ),
                onCodeChanged: (value) {
                  Provider.of<PinValidationProvider>(context, listen: false)
                      .validatePin(value, setPinController);
                },
                onCodeSubmitted: (value) {
                  Provider.of<PinValidationProvider>(context, listen: false)
                      .validateCompletedPin(value, setPinController);
                },
                codeLength: 4,
                cursor: Cursor(color: Colors.black, enabled: true),
                controller: setPinController,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Consumer<PinValidationProvider>(
              builder: (context, provider, child) {
                if (!provider.isPinMatched && setPinController.text.isNotEmpty) {
                  return Text(
                    'Entered PIN does not match.',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  );
                } else if (!provider.isPinSet && setPinController.text.isNotEmpty) {
                  return Text(
                    'Pin must be at least 4 digits. It must not be single digits like'
                    ' 1111 or digits in numerical order such as 1234',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  return SizedBox(); // Return an empty widget when no error is applicable
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: now it changed whole scenario, Which is totally wrong

Comment: what happened? please elaborate

Comment: bro this is hard to elaborate as this code change everything.

Comment: okay as your wish,